# Argh @ my current Extended Discussion in 'Comments'

Tags: discussion

Seems like this "comment" discussion under one of my [Answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/341927/point-domain-to-cpanel-and-google-apps/341928#341928) is becoming pointless. The guys keeps asking questions.

What would YOU do? Walk off and ignore him? Tell him in a new comment to go find his answers elsewhere?

There's two thing I don't want to do:

1. Turn this into a freakish long discussion answering all of his questions
2. Answer basic questions that he could easily find on Google or other questions on Server Fault. (I'm sort of tempted to point him towards LMGTFY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do LMGTFY (links to that site are disabled anyways). I would tell him that it sounds like he needs to open a new question on the site, as it's getting outside the scope of his first question. Then you can walk away with a clean conscience.

Answer (score 6):

Walk away. Some people are beyond help. We're not here to do their jobs for them.

Comment: I approve. Now post your gravatar to my Meta!

Answer (score 3):

LMGTFY is frowned upon.

I'd add one last comment along the lines of "you need to figure out how to do that for yourself," and then bail.

Comment: There you go, Shads added an appropriate comment for you.

Comment: Yup, he beat me to the punch (Thank you, Shads)! Yes, I was 1/2 joking with LMGTFY, and I'm happy to hear that its blocked from SF - it would just make all of us look like a bunch of complaining, unhelpful idiots. Although server admins in general are a rare breed, that's for sure. 

Thanks for the suggestions / responses, Holocryptic and @Ward.

Comment: Well, to be fair, we *do* complain a lot....

Answer (score 1):

Definitely walk away. We're to read, ask and answer questions (or any combination thereof), not to have arguments about them. Walking away reminds me of the old "What's the best way to keep a fool in suspense?".